# does pointwise convergence mean that the support is shrinking?

Tags: terminology

A simple example

Let $f_n = n \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0, 1/n)}$

the function converges pointwise to 0. Can I also say that **the support of f is shrinking** or is it best to just keep the phrasing: the function converges pointwise to 0?

Comment: The sequence doesn't converge to $0$ at $0$ though.

Comment: @Arthur : though $g_n = n \cdot \mathbb{1}_{(0, 1/n)}$ would

Comment: that's fine since it's pointwise and not uniform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example the support is shrinking indeed. However, the information contained in the statement "the support is shrinking" is not sufficient in itself to guarantee pointwise convergence.

Comment: Thank you, this clarified it so much for me

Comment: what is the correct statement btw? is "shrinking support" correct? also, what does vanishing support mean? I might be getting it mixed up a bit here.

Answer (score 0):

No. If $f_n\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is defined by $f_n(x)=\frac1n$, then $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges pointwise to the null function, but the support of each $f_n$ is equal to $\mathbb R$,

Comment: That seems to ignore the $\mathbb{1}_{[0, 1/n)}$ term.  The support of the original function $f_n$ looks to me like $[0,\frac1n]$

Comment: That is supposed to be just an example. The actual question is “does pointwise convergence mean that the support is shrinking?” and my answer explains that the answer to that question is negative.

Comment: OK - my confusion was the use of the same $f_n$ notation for a different example.  My guess is that at some stage the question will motivated by probability density functions with $\int f_n(x) \, dx =1$

Comment: This answer was also really good, thank you. It clarifies it for me.